# Java Use compareTo to Compare Two Objects

Tags: java, object, compareto

I am to write a method which will implement the `compareTo` method to compare the objects in my array to decide which is the biggest. Here is my code:

```
public static Object max(Object[] array) {
    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        Object lol = (array[0].compareTo(array[i]));     
    }
    return; // what should be returned?
}
```

Could anyone explain to me how to actually use `compareTo`, and what it should return?

Comment: Do you really mean `Object` or some type implementing `Comparable`?

Comment: What is the data type of your array?

Comment: Is the question about implementing `compareTo` or `max` ?

Comment: They are Strings. I want to implement compareTo and I think I need Comparable for that.

Comment: String out of the box is Comparable, unless you want to implement some custom sorting. In that case you should consider Comparator. Can you be a bit more specific about what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need something like this.

```
Object biggestObject = array[0];
    for (Object obj: array){
        if (biggestObject.compareTo(obj) == 1){
            biggestObject = obj;
        }
    }
 return biggestObject;
```

If you are using a custom object you are going to need to override the compareTo method so like if the object is a person and we are comparing  Pen... feet size, then we would want to set up compareTo to compare feet sizes, returning 1 when the object being compared to is bigger, 0 if its the same, and -1 if its smaller.

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object obj){
    if (this.feetSize < obj.getFeetSize()){
        return 1;
    etc, etc....
```

Comment: Should be `> 0` not `> 1`. `compareTo` should never return a value greater than 1.

Comment: Just a small question, what does for (Object obj: array) mean? I can't find anything about it.

Comment: @Baxtex (Object obj: array) Look up advanced for loop. 
Simply is means, for every Object in array do the following. where obj will be the reference used in each iteration of that for loop.